# How can I override geometry's scale in the preamble? (E.g. if a class or package has set a default using geometry.)

Tags: margins, geometry, package-writing, documentclass-writing, preamble

With some `geometry` options, it is possible to override a previous setting in the preamble. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmarginratio=1:1}
\geometry{showframe,hmarginratio=6:1}

\begin{document}

  abc

\end{document}
```

[image: hmarginratio switch]

With others, this method does not work. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{scale=.85}
\geometry{showframe,scale=.25}

\begin{document}

  abc

\end{document}
```

[image: first setting sticks]

Is there a good reason for this difference and is there a workaround?

The reason I'd like to do this is so that I can have a class or package set a default value for `scale` using `\geometry{}` but allow the possibility of overriding this in the document preamble.

Comment: I guess that the first `scale` option sets `\textwidth` and `\textheight`, so the second is ineffective because of the priority rules of section 6.3; this is however unexpected. If I look at the final values of `\Gm@hscale` and `\Gm@vscale` they are as stated (`.85` in one case, `.0.25` in the other).

Comment: all you need is `\newgeometry{showframe,scale=.25}`

Comment: @touhami I want to know if I can override it in the preamble. I cannot use `\newgeometry` until after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Can you use `AtBeginDocument` or various document hooks provided `etoolbox`?

Comment: I mean you can use it in the preamble. It work for me

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes. I already am. I don't want to overwrite all the default settings, though. I was wondering about putting the `\geometry` in the package/class into the `\AtEndPreamble` hook. Presumably, that way, any `scale` I set in the preamble should 'stick' since the later call won't override it. However, I'd have to separate out the different geometry settings else I wouldn't be able to override the non-sticky ones. It is kind of annoying....

Comment: @touhami It is not supposed to work in the preamble... But, in any case, it will wipe any other defaults I've set which is not good.

Comment: @touhami You're right, though. It does work (in that it definitely has an effect) and there is no error even though the docs say that the command isn't even available until after `\begin{document}`....

Comment: and what about `\textheight=\dimexpr.85\paperheight\relax` in your class?

Comment: @touhami But that will mess up `geometry`'s calculations, won't it? That is, if you're using `geometry`, you want `geometry` to have all the information and create problems if you specify dimensions manually.... Plus, that is not equivalent to `scale=.85` in any case.

Comment: I am not sure, you can use this befor or after loading geometry and it will not cause any problem. i think geometry do the calculation in each call.

Comment: @touhami It causes problems if you set dimensions manually rather than using `\geometry`. If you use that setting before loading the package, it causes no problems as it has no effect. If you use it afterwards, geometry doesn't know you've changed the text height and doesn't take that into account. In any case, that is not the same as `scale=.85`.

Comment: yes you're right it causes problem.

Comment: @touhami Too bad, though. I've just been experimenting and getting weird results...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is the full solution, but it's too long for a comment (and I've not figured out what could go wrong in here)

Looking into documenation of `geometry`:

> reset sets back the layout dimensions and switches to the settings
>   before geometry is loaded. Options given in geometry.cfg are also
>   cleared. Note that this cannot reset pass and mag with truedimen.
>   reset=false has no eect and cannot cancel the previous reset(=true)
>   if any.

So `reset` might be the correct option for `\geometry` in preamble

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{verbose,showframe,scale=.85}



\geometry{reset,verbose,showframe,scale=0.25,lmargin=2in}

\begin{document}

  abc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I missed this answer because the system didn't tell me anybody had answered. If you'd not asked in chat, I wouldn't have found it. This might be helpful although, as it stands, it will undo all geometry settings, if I've understood correctly, and I only want to override the ones I explicitly set in the preamble. I'm wondering if I can use it in conjunction with some trick. (Or if I should just give this up and workaround it in some other way, which is what I ended up doing for the document I was trying to finish last night.)

Comment: @cfr: I digged somehow into `geometry.sty`, but it's too complicated at the moment to find the precise control flow which allows for multiple calls of `\geometry` and which options can be added again.